# TCP/IP Connection call from External Csharp Dynamic Link Library blocked by Firewall

Tags: c#, sockets, firewall, tcp

I think most of TCP/IP Connection problem deals with exe files on the net. I could not find any straight forward answer for my specific problem for the case of using the external Dynamic Link Library building the TCP/IP connection.

I build a simple Server and Client application for remote communication purpose. They are written in c sharp dll.

The third party exe will use my custom dynamic Link library to call the TCP/IP connection inside my dll library (the external DLL was written from C Sharp) for both server and client application.

For your information, I do not have any access to change anything in that third party exe file but only I can change anything in my Dynamic Link Library. The dll also use only one port for communication.

Everything works fine when I switched off the Firewall on my Public network. However, as soon as I switch on the firewall, the connection can not be made any more.

1. I tried to create inbound rule to allow a specific port in my firewall, used by my TCP/IP application. But this approach does not work although it should work. Even I created outbound rule to allow the same port. But it never works.
2. I also tried to grant the admin right by setting this on the manifest file inside my dll file programmatically. But again nothing happens.

> requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"

3. I started the main exe file with admin right. But this also does not work.

Because the dll file is calling the TCP/IP connection, I can not set the program rule for the dll file in my firewall. I think only exe file can use the programme rule in the firewall.

So I tried to build the equivalent standalone exe file instead of my dll file. I have created new inbound rule for Program allowing the standalone exe file in my firewall. Everything worked perfectly again. Both server exe and client exe app can communicate without any problem.

Things will be simpler think this way. If firewall is switched off, the tcp connection works fine. This is definitely some clue.

1. The question is how to put the firewall back without disturbing the tcp connection for the specific port ?
2. Why I have created inbound and outbound rule to allow the port but never works ?

> Update on 10 Oct 2017:
>
> I have changed the role of server and clients between two PC. The TCP
>   connection worked fine with by setting the port rule in the firewall.
>   Now I can tell the problem is the specific to one of the testing
>   computer, not related to dll or exe problem.
>
> In that problematic computer, the port rule or programme rule neither
>   works except switching off the firewall when it play the server role.
>   Can anything else interfere after the firewall ? or port forwarding
>   can help in this case ? Still looking for the good solution.

Comment: What port number are you using.  TCP is usually blocked by the port number.  It is best to use port numbers above 1,000 since numbers below are reserved to be used by standard protocols.  The standard protocols are what is normally blocked.  I usually like using port numbers above 10,000 which are less often used to prevent conflicts with other applications.

Comment: Currently using above 5000 but it can be changed always.

Comment: It should work above 5000 unless another application is already using the same port number.  Firewall s block by port number so you need to check the firewall options to turn off blocking on specific port numbers.  You may want to also check from cmd.exe that you can ping  remote PC ( and on remote PC can ping local PC).  If ping isn't working then there are other issues.  The firewall may be blocking ICMP messages.  If both computers are on same subnet then check cmd.exe >Arp -a.  The ARP table contains all  the responses from ping messages.

Comment: I tried. The ping does not work from remote PC to local PC. I am assuming this is normal behaviour because the TCP/IP connection was used for the normal personal computer not for server grade computers. isn't the ping is more appropriate solution for checking the broadcasting message like http rather socket programing ? Also is there anyway for ping to check the connection state of specific port ?

Comment: Ping response determines if there is a route between two computers.  You need a route to make a connection.  Ping ignores port numbers so you always try ping as first debug tool.  To get a connection you need an IP route on PC using Mask of PC.  If DHCP you get IP from computer name.  Did you try ping using both IP and computer name?  Did ping work in one direction and not the other direction?